# UITableViewController or UIViewController when adding additional controls

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a number of views that include tableviews, but other controls as well.  Up till now I have been subclassing UIViewController and manually adding a tableview to it (with my other controls above/below it).  Not too much hassle, other than having to manually handle the scrolling, and sometimes some resizing (if the table's content is dynamic).

I only just found that the tableHeaderView and tableFooterView of a UITableView can pretty much handle anything you throw at them.  I guess I skimmed them previously, thinking they were related to section headers/footers when they are of course not related at all.

So with that in mind, and before I convert a bunch of classes over to subclass UITableViewController instead of UIViewController, is this standard practice?  If I have a view, for example, that is mostly non-table content but with a dynamic tableview half way down, is it a good idea simply to use a UITableViewController and put everything around it in the header/footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table view header and footer are scrolled with the table view's content. If you need them to always be visible, your current approach is the best. If you don't mind the header views being scrolled, you can indeed refactor your app.

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I want (and have had to manually create in my UIViewController). One other concern though - how would I handle the situation where I need some additional controls not above or below all the table content, but between sections?  I'm thinking of a simple tableview with two sections, each with one row (maybe 'name' and 'dept' as section headers and the values in the cell. Say I want a label above the dept section. Is there any mechanism for doing this, or will I end up having to convert everything back if in 2 weeks I decide I want a label there?

Comment: I don't think the scenario warrants two table views, so you may want to consider a custom table section header view or a cell in between, it depends on aesthetics. To ease the pain you can create your own generic subclass of `UIViewController` which wraps a table view in its view, so that refactoring involves fewer changes. In fact, I've done this several times and I think it's perfectly OK.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips - I will proceed to refactor a couple of my views and I have a couple of directions to explore now.  Thanks again.

Comment: how did it work out? I'm facing the same issue. In particular I want to know how it works in IB (in a storyboard). I have been actually using a section with a single (Static) cell and placing my extra view (a segmented control) inside that - but I can't seem to hide the cell behind it completely - and in IB you can only select text as the header. I could do it all in code, but I want to see and edit my segmented control

Answer (score 1):

A `UIViewController` manages a view hierarchy. If your view contains significant non-`UITableView` content, I would manage the view hierarchy with a`UIViewController` and include the `UITableView` as a subview in the view controller's `view` property.